# Union de dos variables para crear una tercera array

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Dirección de donde estoy escribiendo el código (no es necesario entrar).](http://codepen.io/scetalv/pen/ZOgLXx)

Estoy haciendo una página donde aparece la descripcion de varios usuarios de twitchTV, correspondiente a un ejercicio de freecodecamp[266]. El caso es que para automatizar el proceso y no tener que escribir cada web + usuario manualmente, se me ha ocurrido usar tres variables, correspondientes a
1) Array con lista de usuarios (lista).
2) String con la url basica (url)
3) String con la url alternativa por si no están online, ya que cambia (urlAlt).
Entonces quería juntarlo todo mediante un bucle `for`, lo cual no sé si es lo apropiado ponerlo ahí sin mas, pero es lo único que se me ocurre. **El problema** es que `console.log` *dentro* del `for`, a pesar de que me devuelve todas las url, lo hace por separado y no juntas, por lo que no debe de estar funcionando y, si saco el `console.log` del `for`, sólo me devuelve la última (https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/noobs2ninjas, aunque creo que en ambos casos el resultado es el mismo).

Supongo que es porque al reiniciar el bucle al principio de todo tiene el comando de vaciar la array (`var lisUrl = [];`), pero no encuentro la manera de solucionarlo.

```
var lista = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var url = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/";
var urlAlt = "https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channels/";


for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    var lisUrl = [];
    var lisAlt = [];
    lisUrl.push(url + lista[i]); // Lo he intentado tambien con: lisUrl += lisUrl.push(url + lista[i])
    lisAlt.push(url + lista[i]);

}
console.log(lisUrl);
```

**Hasta aqui la duda.**
Lo que pongo a continuacion no es parte de la consulta, pero lo añado por si a alguien le apetece aclararmelo:

La segunda parte del codigo es esta:

```
for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    $.getJSON(url + lista[i], function(data) {

        if (data.stream !== null) {
            $("#jugadores").prepend("<div>" + data.stream.viewers + "</div>");
        } //if
        else if (data.stream === null) {
            $.getJSON(urlAlt + lista[i], function(data) {
                $("#jugadores").prepend("<div>" + data.status + "</div>");
            }); //getjson2
        } //else if
    }); //getjson1
} //for


}); //ready
```

Consiste en que primero verifique si con una url se pueden sacar los datos -solo funciona si el usuario está online- y, en caso de que no, usar la url alternativa para acceder a ellos. Me gustaría saber si puedo tener problemas si uno de los usuarios esta offline porque entonces sólo comprobaría el `else if` para el resto de la lista, o si va a probar ambos condicionales con toda la lista.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Supongo que es porque al reiniciar el bucle al principio de todo tiene el comando de vaciar la array (`var lisUrl = [];`)

Es exactamente eso. Inicializá las variables **antes** del bucle:

```js
var lista = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas"];
var url = "http://www.miweb.com/streams/";
var urlAlt = "http://www.miweb.com/channels/";

//Inicializar nuevos arrays
var lisUrl = [];
var lisAlt = [];

//Popularlos
for (var i = 0; i < lista.length; i++) {
    lisUrl.push(url + lista[i]);
    lisAlt.push(urlAlt + lista[i]);
}

//Mostrar contenido
console.log(lisUrl, lisAlt);
```

---

> Me gustaría saber si puedo tener problemas si uno de los usuarios esta offline porque entonces sólo comprobaría el `else if` para el resto de la lista, o si va a probar ambos condicionales con toda la lista.

Lo comprueba para cada llamada a `$.getJSON()`, es decir para cada dirección de la lista.

Por otro lado, un detalle, no es necesario usar un `else if`, ya que el único valor que puede tener en ese punto es `null`.

```
if (valor !== null) {
    // código
} else {
    // código si es null
}
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias.

Comment: @Alsun Me alegro que te haya sido útil. Si crees que esto responde a tu pregunta, por favor considera aceptarla haciendo click en el tilde a la izquierda.

Comment: Hecho. He puesto una segunda pregunta, por si tienes tiempo para mirarla.